# how to get rotation component of quaternion form using 3d coordinates

Tags: 3d, coordinate-systems, quaternions

I have a series of 3d coordinates distributed in a 3d space according to a root point. I can determine the $x$, $y$, and $z$ components by reducing the vectors, but I am not clear on how to get the rotation component in quaternion form. Can someone explain it simply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation) should have exactly what you need.